# Multiple vimeo pattern for magnific popup

Tags: jquery, iframe, popup, magnific-popup

question to those who customized magnific popup - how do I combine multiple vimeo patterns for iframe type in Magnific Popup plugin?
Here is the video urls I need to play and their patterns:

> https://player.vimeo.com/external/xxxxx.hd.mp4

```
patterns: {
    ...
    vimeo: {
       index: '//vimeo.com/',
       id: '/',
       src: '//player.vimeo.com/external/%id%'
    },
    ...
}
```

> https://vimeo.com/xxxx

```
patterns: {
    ...
    vimeo: {
       index: 'vimeo.com/',
       id: '/',
       src: '//player.vimeo.com/video/%id%?autoplay=1'
    },
    ...
}
```

Each pattern works individually, but the question is how to use them together?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to use id as a function:

```
patterns: {
      vimeo: {
        index: 'vimeo.com/',
        id: function(src){
           if (src.indexOf('external') > -1) {
              return 'external/' + src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('/')+1, src.length);
           } else {
              return 'video/' + src.substr(src.lastIndexOf('/')+1, src.length);
           }
        },
        src: '//player.vimeo.com/%id%?autoplay=1'
      },
    },
```